# Neo4j: Loading CSV file combined with substring function

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load a *.csv file into neo4j and in the same load statement split the line (which has no delimiters but has a set location for the data that I need to create nodes from). I want to use the substring function, I can't figure out how to get it to work. The data reads in as a single line:

0067011990999991958051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9+00001+99999999999

I have tried using the following code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/c:/itw/Ltemps.csv" AS line
WITH line
WHERE line.year IS split((substring(line, 15, 19))) and line.temp IS split((substring(line, 88, 92))) and line.qlfr IS split((substring(line, 87, 88))) and line.qual IS split((substring(line, 92, 93)))
MERGE (y:Year {year:line.year})
MERGE (t:Temp {temp:line.temp})
MERGE (f:Qlfr {qlfr:line.qlfr})
MERGE (q:Qual {qual:line.qual})
CREATE (y)-[r:HAS_TEMP]->(t);
```

I am looking to get 4 nodes: year, temp (an absolute value), a qualifier (positive or negative symbol), and a quality number. The indexes on for where the data lies in the string should be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's try to get the indexes and types right. To convert numeric substrings to integers, we use the [`toInteger`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger) function:

```
WITH '0067011990999991958051507004+68750+023550FM-12+038299999V0203301N00671220001CN9999999N9+00001+99999999999' AS line
RETURN
  toInteger(substring(line, 15, 4)) AS year,
  toInteger(substring(line, 88, 2)) AS temp,
  substring(line, 87, 1) AS qlfr,
  toInteger(substring(line, 92, 1)) AS qual
```

This gives:

```
╒══════╤══════╤══════╤══════╕
│"year"│"temp"│"qlfr"│"qual"│
╞══════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│1958  │0     │"+"   │1     │
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

If the results good look, add back `LOAD CSV` the `MERGE` clauses. Two things:

- I don't think it makes sense to use `WITH HEADERS`, as headers are useless in this case. Simply load the row and use `row[0]` as the `line` for splitting.
- It is possible to simplify the `MERGE` by combining the your first two `MERGE` clauses with the `CREATE` clause.

So the loader code is the following:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:/c:/itw/Ltemps.csv' AS row
WITH row[0] AS line
WITH
  toInteger(substring(line, 15, 4)) AS year,
  toInteger(substring(line, 88, 2)) AS temp,
  substring(line, 87, 1) AS qlfr,
  toInteger(substring(line, 92, 1)) AS qual
MERGE (y:Year {year: year})-[r:HAS_TEMP]->(t:Temp {temp: temp})
MERGE (f:Qlfr {qlfr: qlfr})
MERGE (q:Qual {qual: qual})
```